# Extracting data from a string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a string and want to extract data from it.

```
$str = "Online (UVD) - 154,842 - Last Updated: Nov 23 2015 02:24 PM";
```

I want this `154,842` extract and this `2015` I've successfully extracted the first part. with this method

```
trim(str_replace("Online (UVD) - ", "", str_replace(",", "", substr_replace($str, "", strpos($str, " - Last Updated"))), $str))
```

Now, I'm unsure how to extract the other one. Data can vary for instance,

```
$str = "Online (UVD) - 1123123 - Last Updated: Nov 23 2015 02:24 PM";
$str = "Online (UVD) - 12 - Last Updated: Nov 23 2015 02:24 PM";
$str = "Online (UVD) - 1546546 - Last Updated: Nov 23 2015 02:24 PM";
$str = "Online (UVD) - 3525252525 - Last Updated: Nov 23 2015 02:24 PM";
```

Is there a better method to extract?/

Comment: check this one https://regex101.com/r/NOi7wZ/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the strings will always have the same number of values perhaps `explode` and then using specific array positions would work for you.

```
$str = "Online (UVD) - 154,842 - Last Updated: Nov 23 2015 02:24 PM";
$pieces = explode(' ',$str);
echo 'Value is ' . $pieces[3] . ' and the year is ' . $pieces[9];
```

Comment: Exactly the code I was going to recommend. Avoid regex when possible.

Comment: Thanks. I know explode but it didn't cross my mind :D

Comment: If an extra space is introduced before the value he wants, this will not work. We should support `regex` instead of `explode`, `replaces`, `etc` imho

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using **regex** if all the words in the string are in same order that you provided. Let's try with [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) -

```
<?php
$str = "Online (UVD) - 1123123 - Last Updated: Nov 23 2015 02:24 PM";
$str = "Online (UVD) - 12 - Last Updated: Nov 23 2015 02:24 PM";
$str = "Online (UVD) - 1546546 - Last Updated: Nov 23 2015 02:24 PM";
$str = "Online (UVD) - 3525252525 - Last Updated: Nov 23 2015 02:24 PM";

$digit = explode(' ',$str);
echo trim($digit[3]); // returns digits
echo trim($digit[9]); // returns date
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/ttBDG

Comment: Thanks mate. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is answered but I think on also providing a `regex` solution for this:

To extract your **1st group**, you can use bellow regex:

```
preg_match('/.-.(\d+).-/', $str, $numExtracted);

if (!empty($numExtracted)) {
    echo $numExtracted[1].PHP_EOL;   
}
```

To extract your **Year**:

```
preg_match('/(\w\w\w).(\d\d).(\d\d\d\d)/', $str, $year, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$year = $year[3][0];
echo $year.PHP_EOL;
```

This worked on all of the below trials:

```
Online (UVD) - 1123123 - Last Updated: Nov 23 2015 02:24 PM
Online (UVD) - 12 - Last Updated: Nov 23 2015 02:24 PM
Online (UVD) oi oi    -            1546546 - Last Updated: Nov 23 2015 02:24 PM
Online -sdtgstg346fg - (UVD) - 3525252525 - Last Updated:             Nov 23 2015 02:24 PM
```

You can check the working code [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8fa10741856dde1d86744e4c9978454992925534)

As per you comment question, you can enhance your regex to consider such cases:

```
.-.(\d+)?[\,\#\!\?\$\£\;\:]*(\d+)?.-
```

It will match all of the above plus this cases:

```
Online (UVD) - 1123,123 - Last Updated: Nov 23 2015 02:24 PM
Online (UVD) - 1123#!,123 - Last Updated: Nov 23 2015 02:24 PM
```

But I think there is a time you need to consider if you want to have a hold on the information you received or just consider it corrupt.

You can even introduce cycles to parse to every single case scenario but if I am expecting a number and suddenly the `regex` that triggers a match is for something like `1A2B3C4G5D8D2F` I will discard it as it goes far from what I initially expected. But it all depends from where you receive your information, how likely is it to change, etc :)

Still, I think `regex` will make you happier and assert far more possibilities

PS: For the special cases introduced, because the number is interrupted by special chars (or even words if you consider them) it now interprets and 2 numbers.

Comment: Hey what about this `Online (UVD) - 1123,123 - Last Updated: Nov 23 2015 02:24 PM`

Comment: This doesn't get parsed.

Comment: And which would you be interested in grabbing on that occasion? the 1st or second? I think you can consider when you can have a hold of the information you received on when that information is just simply corrupt and you can not simply trust it

Comment: @AliRasheed updated my answer to answer to your secondary question :) Let me know if it makes sense!

Comment: This does make sense